# Use Media Youtube with File Field Type

Tags: feeds, media, files

I have set up a Feed Importer than gets a YouTube Atom Feed and processes it into "YouTube Video" content type. This is working great so far but what I want to do now is have the actual YouTube video embedded in my website rather that linking to the youtube website.

I downloaded and installed the [Media YouTube](http://drupal.org/project/media_youtube) module and went to set up a field in the YouTube Video content type to hold the video url. The Multimedia Asset field type is deprecated and I found somewhere that said to use the File field type. So I created the "Video" field as a File field with the Media File Selector widget. Then I set up the mapping in the feed importer. I am using the [Feeds: YouTube Parser](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_youtube) module to parse the Atom Feed. I set the Source to Video URL and the Target to my new Video field.

When I went to import the feed I got a bunch of errors that look like this

Download of http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tag:youtube.com,2008:video:xm6Jv3BhdS4 failed with code 404.

I'm not sure where the "tag:youtube.com,2008:video:" part is coming from otherwise the url is correct. Anyone know what my problem is? Is it the way the YouTube Parser is getting the url or something else?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your feed importer mapping, change the Source to `Watch page`.  It seems `Video URL` is broken.

I have it working right now with the following modules:

- Feeds (feeds)  7.x-2.0-alpha7
- Feeds: YouTube (feeds_youtube)  7.x-2.0-beta1+7-dev
- Media Feeds (media_feeds)  7.x-2.0-alpha1+9-dev
- Media (media)  7.x-1.2
- Media Internet Sources (media_internet)  7.x-1.2
- Media: YouTube (media_youtube)  7.x-2.0-rc1

All dev versions were as of today (Dec. 1, 2012).  And for anyone that's trying, I found Embedded Media Field (emfield) to not work with Feeds at all.

Using the File field type (the widget type doesn't matter for feeds imports), set the display to Rendered file.